# How to evaluate the accuray of quadratic eigenvalue problem (QEP)?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

When solving the QEP, we transform it into a GEP and then use qz algorithm to handle it.

But there are several formulations of GEP, how to evaluate the accuracy and stability of the solution?

I have met with some measures including backward error and condition numbers?
But the evaluation of GEP seems not to be enough to represent the performance of QEP.

Maybe someone could recommand some articles?